# increasing sum of the elements of a list

Tags: ocaml

How to compute the sum of each element of a list multiplied by it's index position in OCaml? example: for [4;7;9] the result is  45 (4x1 + 7x2 + 9x3 = 45). the only authorized functions are List.hd, List.tl et List.length.

I can do it in the other direction with this code:

```
let  rec sum l =
    let n = (List.length l) + 1    in 
    if l = [] then 0 else
     ((List.hd l)*(n-1))+ (sum(List.tl l)) ;;

sum [4;7;9];;
- : int = 35  (4x3 + 7x2 + 9x1 = 35)
```

But the expected result is 45 (4x1 + 7x2 + 9x3 = 45).
thank you for your help.

Comment: Why don't you just let n be 0 then increment n instead of decrementing it from the length + 1?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already tried this solution. this is what I  got:                      
      let  rec sum l =
    let n = 0   in 
    if l = [] then 0 else
     ((List.hd l)*(n+1))+ (sum(List.tl l)) ;;
                                                                                                                                        
   sum [4;7;9];;
- : int = 20  (4x1 + 7x1 + 9x1 =20) .                                                                                              
 But I want to get 45 (4x1 + 7x2 + 9x3 = 45). I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: This code sets `n` to 0 at every call. You need an extra parameter to maintain `n` across the recursive calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I'd probably do something like this..

```
let rec new_sum l n =
  match l with
  | [] -> 0
  | head::tail -> (head * n) + new_sum tail (n+1)

let sum l =
  new_sum l 1;;
  
sum [4;7;9]
```

...if you don't like the guards for pattern matching, and prefer `List.hd`, `List.tl`, `List.length` then you could use...

```
let rec new_sum l n =
  if (List.length l == 0) then 0
  else ((List.hd l) * n) + new_sum (List.tl l) (n+1)

let sum l =
  new_sum l 1;;
  
sum [4;7;9];
```

Comment: Thank you very much, now I understand why it was not working. You solved my problem.

Comment: No worries. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Using `List.hd`, `List.tl`, and `List.length`, I'd use a locally scoped helper function to both avoid repeated calculations of the length, and to enable a tail-recursive solution.

```
# let sum lst =
    let len = List.length lst in
    let rec aux lst i sum =
      if i = 0 then sum
      else aux (List.tl lst) (i - 1) (sum + List.hd lst * i)
    in
    aux lst len 0;;
val sum : int list -> int = <fun>
# sum [4; 7; 9];;
- : int = 35
```

If we trace this out:

```
sum [4; 7; 9]
aux [4; 7; 9] 3 0
aux [7; 9] 2 12
aux [9] 1 26
aux [] 0 35
35
```